# Backbone: Destroy previous view and use of Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It is a login flow where user gives the login details and gets the response back from server. 
Here I am not able to figure out that where should I remove previous view? Does `dashboard View` need to know about `LoginView`.
What is the use of `Router`? Does flow ever come to Router in this scenario? 

**Both Views**

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
    template:_.template('<div class="form-signin">'+
                        '<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>'+
                        '<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">'+
                        '<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">'+
                        '<button id="loginBtn" href="#login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Sign in</button>'+
                        '</div>'),
    events: {
        "click #loginBtn":"login"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    },
    login: function() {
      console.log('view signIn');
      this.model.set({
        "email": $('#email').val(),
        "password": $('#password').val()
      });
      this.model.login();
    }
});

var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template('<div>'+
                        '<h3><%= campaignName %></h3>'+
                        '<span><%= orderedAndGoal %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= status %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= endDate %>, </span>'+
                        '</div>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('what happens here')
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
            this.$el.appendTo('.container');
    },
});
var dashboardView = new DashboardView({model: dashboardModel});
```

**Both Models**

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login',

    defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log('Model: Got the response back');
        return resp;
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log('Model: Login function:'+JSON.stringify(this));
        this.save(
            {}, {
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log('success'+JSON.stringify(resp.get("0")));
                    dashboardModel.set(resp.get("0"));
                    //window.location = 'templates/dashboard.html'
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
    },
    redirect: function() {
        console.log('inside redirect method');
    }
});
var loginModel = new LoginModel();

var DashboardModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        campaignName:"",
        orderedAndGoal:"",
        status:"",
        endDate:"",
        orderPlace:"",
        tShirtOrdered:"",
        tippingPoint:"",
        getPaid:""
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log('Model: Got the response back');
        return resp;
    }
});
var dashboardModel = new DashboardModel();
```

When `LoginModel.save()` gets the values from server and set it to `DashboardModel`. `DashboardView` listens to the change in model. It then calls the `render()`. It all makes sense. But where to go after that?
Is it a good idea to append `DashboardView.el` to parent tag in it's `render()`?
Is there any use of `Router` here?
Application's router looks like this:

```
var Router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":"home",
        "login":"login"
    },
    start: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
    },
    home: function() {
        var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
        loginView.render();
        $(".container").append(loginView.el);
    }, 
    login: function() {
        var loginModel = new LoginModel();
        var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
        loginModel.fetch();     
    }
}));

new Router.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your questions

1. Here I am not able to figure out that where should I remove previous view?

   **A:** Views can be replaced or appended in the DOM, it depends on the app needs.
2. Does dashboard View need to know about LoginView?

   **A:** Views don't need to know about other views. Pass this responsibility to the router/controller or save data in a common model that both views can share.
3. What is the use of Router? Does flow ever come to Router in this scenario?

   **A:** Backbone Routers listen to the url changes but they are the proper place to listen to view events, so if your view makes an important change they can react accordingly. This is from Backbone documentation:

   > Backbone.Router provides methods for routing client-side pages, and connecting them to actions and events.

## Your example

In the code you provide both routes create a login view:

```
home: function() {
    var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
    loginView.render();
    $(".container").append(loginView.el);
},
login: function() {
    var loginModel = new LoginModel();
    var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
    loginModel.fetch();
}
```

What you could do is to have a route for login and another for dashboard:

- **the login route**, create the view and after the login is succeed save the session in a cookie.
- in the dashboard route you check if the session is avaliable and only render the content if it exists, if not you redirect to login.

There are plenty of good articles about user authentication, I point you [this example](http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2012/01/11/backbonejs-sessions-and-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

You can append your view to an element in the DOM. You can do it after you render like so:

```
render: function() {
    console.log('what happens here')
    var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
    this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    this.$el.appendTo('#yourElement');
},
```

Or, you can set to view to attach an element when you create your view:

```
var dashboardView = new DashboardView({
                        model: dashboardModel,
                        el: $('#yourElement')
                    });
```

Also, if you want to replace your loginView with your DashboardView you need to .remove() your old view and append your DashboardView to the same container element.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. Where would I remove the first view? What is the use of Router here?